# Google chart api explorer vs. selecthandler

Tags: javascript, css, charts, google-visualization

I have problem with using Google.charts api... i have chart drawing function like this:

```
      function columnDraw(sectionname) {

       var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(array);
       var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
       var options = {
          title: "Activity of users",
           bar: {groupWidth: "100%"},
         legend: {position: "top"},
          height: 300,
          // explorer: {
               //maxZoomOut:0
               //maxZoomIn: 50,
               // keepInBounds: true,
               // axis: 'horizontal'
          // },
           hAxis: {
               title: 'Amount of activity',
               minValue : 0,
               format: '0'
           },
           vAxis: {
               title: 'Amount of users',
               minValue : 0,
               format: '0'

           }


       };
       var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById(sectionname));

       function selectHandler() {
           var selectedItem = chart.getSelection()[0];
           if (selectedItem) {
               document.getElementById("input0").value = data.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);
           }
       }
       google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);
       chart.draw(view, options);
   }
```

I want to choose parts of chartcolumn by cklicing on them, but i have a problem  with zooming. This code works but once I uncomment the explorer part, selectHandler function wont work properly. Can anyone tell me whats wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a ","

```
           maxZoomOut:0,
```

Comment: thnak you, but thats not it